# fbprophet predict() method scalar values error

Tags: python, pandas, facebook-prophet

I'm trying to follow [the basic tutorial for fbprophet](https://facebook.github.io/prophet/docs/quick_start.html) and am getting an error that doesn't really make sense on the Prophet.predict() method. My code follows the tutorial exactly:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from fbprophet import Prophet

df = pd.read_csv("example_wp_peyton_manning.csv")
df['y'] = np.log(df['y'])
m = Prophet()
m.fit(df)
future = m.make_future_dataframe(periods = 365)
forecast = m.predict(future)
```

on the predict method, I get

```
ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index
```

I've seen this before when trying to use DataFrame constructors improperly, but this seems to be happening under the hood in the fbprophet code, which is strange because the passed dataframe comes from the package's own make_future_dataframe method. Has anyone else experienced this/know a work-around?

For context, I'm using Python 3.6.0, with Visual C++ 14.0, Numpy 1.13.1, Pandas 0.21.0, pystan 2.17.0.0 and fbprophet 0.2

There doesn't seem to be a tag for fbprophet and I don't have the reputation to make one

Comment: Can up upload a link to the file?

Comment: The file from the example is [here](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/master/examples/example_wp_peyton_manning.csv).

Answer (score 0):

I got some other error but it works after adding:

```
...
m = Prophet()
m.daily_seasonality=True
...
```

[image]

Comment: I get a warning about daily seasonality but that's expected since it's a daily series. I'm still getting the scalar values error either way. There must be something weird about my installation.

Comment: Are you using pop?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should try python 2.

Comment: Any particular reason? It's not like fbprophet is older than python 3.

Comment: Do you want to understand why or to solve you issue?

Comment: Both, really. Solving my issue is sort of secondary to being able to solve this kind of issue on my own, and understanding why might be part of that.

Comment: If it's secondary, then open the source of fbprophet and debug it... Probably the issue there.